# How Do I Create Working Android Virtual Devices for Nexus 7 and UG007 MiniPC?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.android, xamarin, android-virtual-device

Xamarin Studio Business Edition has a device definition for the Nexus 7 but the AVD I created from the device throws an `internal error` when attempting to deploy with Xamarin Studio and hangs at the `Waiting for Device...` point in Visual Studio 2012.

I had the same problem with the UG007 MiniPC.

For more details on how I created the AVDs and set minimum Android versions see [Setting Up Xamarin Studio Business Edition v4.0.3 for Google Nexus 7 and UG007 MiniPC Development](http://oakleafblog.blogspot.com/2013/04/setting-up-xamarin-studio-business.html).

For more details about the UG007 Android MiniPC, see [First Look at the CozySwan UG007 and Other Android 4.1+ MiniPC Devices](http://oakleafblog.blogspot.com/2013/01/first-look-at-cozyswan-ug007-android-41.html).

Thanks in advance for any light you can shed on what I did wrong.

Comment: Can you run: adb logcat (adb is in your android\platform-tools folder).  This will output logs.

Comment: I specified adding monodroid.log to the desktop in VS 2012's Tools | Options | Xamarin window, which reported: Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidLogger Verbose: 0 : -- Start Push - 04/09/2013 11:44:42 (117.168ms) --
Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidLogger Verbose: 0 : [INPUT] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-armeabi-v7a.apk : /data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-armeabi-v7a.apk
Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidLogger Verbose: 0 : [OUTPUT]
Faulted: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Mono.AndroidTools.AdbException: No such file or directory

Comment: I’ve uploaded the full monodroid.log and a capture of the exception details window to the public Xamarin Studio folder of my SkyDrive account at http://sdrv.ms/149n2t3.